# understanding add_post_meta WordPress method?

Tags: wordpress

could any one explain for me the **add_post_meta** WordPress method, I have read the codex but still I do not understand the method ?

I wrote this example, but the output was just number, I do not know what that number is and I do not know how this method could help me.

```
add_shortcode("haidar",'run_haidar');

function run_haidar($attr, $content)
{


    $meta = add_post_meta( 90, 'my_key', 'The quick, brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' ); 

    return $meta;

}
```

clear example would be appreciated.

thanks every body

Comment: `90` is the ID of the post. `my_key` is the meta key and `The quick, brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.` is your meta value.

Comment: @henrywright could you explain for me,  how can I benefit from the value.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25127645/1709033) which explains it nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you're referring to is probably the return value (0/1 - true/false) which you don't need. There are a number of flaws with your original example including setting the result of add_post_meta to a variable titled `$meta` and returning a non-existent variable, `$m`.

Here's what I think you're attempting to do:

```
function run_haidar( $attr, $content ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta( 90, 'my_key', true ); 
    return $meta;
}
add_shortcode( 'haidar','run_haidar' );
```

add_post_meta sets the meta value whereas what you need to do is get it. You'll use get_post_meta instead - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

This will get the meta value of 'my_key' on post 90 and output it in the shortcode. Go into post 90 and set a value for my_key.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I need exactly.
Sorry for the error, just I forget to change the name of the variable.